# Does there exists a theorem like this?

Tags: approximation-theory

**Statement**: Suppose $T\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, then all $x^i,i\in T$ generate a dense linear subspace of $C^0[a,b]$ iff $\sum_{i\in T} 1/i$ is divergent.

I heard it somewhere a long time ago, so there may be minor errors, but the meaning goes like this. I heard it was called a "Bernstein problem", but I never succeeded in searching for such a theorem on the web.

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) is what you're thinking of.

Comment: @DavidMitra, exactly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent reference, not mentioned in the Wikipedia article, is section 4.2 of [Polynomials and Polynomial Inequalities](http://books.google.com/books?id=386CC7JnuuwC) by Borwein and Erdélyi. On 35 pages of that section the authors collect a huge number of variations of the theorem (and then return to it in 4.4 in the setting of rational functions).

Here is a sample.

**Theorem 4.2.1**  Suppose $(\lambda_n)$ is a sequence of distinct positive numbers. Then the span of $x^{\lambda_n}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ if and only if 
$$\sum_{n} \frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_n^2+1}=\infty \tag1$$

Condition (1) simplifies to $\sum_n \lambda_n^{-1}=\infty$ when $\inf \lambda_n>0$.

And a rational version:

**Theorem 4.4.1** Let $(\lambda_n)$ be any sequence of distinct real numbers. Then, for any $0<a<b$,  the set 
$$\left\{ \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^{\lambda_n}}{\sum_{n=0}^N b_n x^{\lambda_n}}  : a_n,b_n\in\mathbb R, \ N=1,2,3\dots \right\}$$
is dense in $C[a,b]$.

Comment: Very helpful. But there are two things I don't understand: 1. What does $\inf \lambda_n>0$ mean? Isn't it $\inf \lambda_n=\infty$? 2. Does $a_n,b_n$ means all $a_n,b_n$?